# getting noise as output instead of mixed sounds

Tags: android, audio, audiotrack

When I run the following code I have no sound as output instead it gives me noise.

I have two audio files in my resource folder and using 1 inputstream these are converted to bytearray.If I add mp3 then the app closes unfortunately.

```
    private void mixSound() throws IOException {
AudioTrack audioTrack =new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,44100,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 44100, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
        Log.i(tag,"inside mixSound");
        InputStream in1=getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cut1);      s
        InputStream in2=getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cut2);

        byte[] music1 = null;
        music1= new byte[in1.available()]; 
        Log.i(tag,"in1");
        music1=convertStreamToByteArray(in1);
        in1.close();


        byte[] music2 = null;
        music2= new byte[in2.available()]; 
        music2=convertStreamToByteArray(in2);
        in2.close();
        byte[] output = new byte[music1.length];

        audioTrack.play();

        for(int i=0; i < output.length; i++){

            float samplef1 = music1[i] / 128.0f;      //     2^7=128
            float samplef2 = music2[i] / 128.0f;


            float mixed = samplef1 + samplef2;
            // reduce the volume a bit:
            mixed *= 0.8;
            // hard clipping
            if (mixed > 1.0f) mixed = 1.0f;

            if (mixed < -1.0f) mixed = -1.0f;

            byte outputSample = (byte)(mixed * 128.0f);
            output[i] = outputSample;

        }   //for loop
        audioTrack.write(output, 0, output.length);

    }

      public static byte[] convertStreamToByteArray(InputStream is) throws IOException {



            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buff = new byte[10240];
            int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            Log.i(tag,"in csb");
            while ((i = is.read(buff, 0, buff.length)) > 0) {
                baos.write(buff, 0, i);
            }

            return baos.toByteArray(); 
        }
```

Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: Which format are your audio files in?

Comment: i used wav format of files for this. but still it did not work.

Comment: I meant more specifically than that. Does the file contain any header data? Is the audio compressed or raw PCM? Does it use 8 or 16 bits per sample?

Comment: Have you got any solution ?? Please share

Answer (score 0):

A few issues here...

1. If you are working with 16-bit PCM audio (which by your initialization of `AudioTrack` it appears you are), then you should access your source audio and write to your `AudioTrack` in `short`s (which are 16 bits) rather than `byte`s (8 bits). If you must read `byte`s from your source, you'll need to read two of them at a time in your loop and do something like

   ```
   short curSample = (myByteArr[i] << 8) | myByteArr[i+1];
   ```

   and then write the result to your stored buffer. This is assuming you have 16-bit shorts stored in the files you're reading from, which you should. Better to just read those as what they are, though.
2. Using `AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM` implies you will write continuously to the buffer while audio is playing. The way you've done it here fills the entire buffer and then writes it to the `AudioTrack`. If this is a one-off playback, you should probably use `AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC`.
3. This is a corner case, but consider what happens if `mixed == 1.0f`. If you multiply that by 128.0f and truncate to `byte`, you'll get 128, which is actually beyond the range of a signed `byte` (because of 0, the range is [-128, 127]).

I believe problem #1 is the source of your noise. You need to keep your 16-bit PCM data intact rather than splitting it up.